# How can I assign multiple classes to a layer in TileMill?

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

In my TileMill project, I have `my-class` that is assigned to most of my layers. I also have `my-other-class` that I want to assign to just a few of those layers. I tried assigning 2 classes using a comma, a semicolon, and a period, but all methods either gave me an error or failed silently. Is it possible to assign multiple classes to a layer?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to assigning CSS classes in HTML tags, multiple CartoCSS classes must be separated with a space. In the project's .mml file:

```
"class": "my-class my-other-class"
```